# Letter Spacing on Curves SVG Makes Letters Tilted Using D3

Tags: svg, d3.js, inkscape, letter-spacing

When I add `letter-spacing` style to my text on path in D3, it tilts the letters and they don't follow nicely the circle anymore (see highlighted letters on image 2)

[image]
[image]

You can see [my D3 code in this notebook](https://observablehq.com/d/f25fb50b658f68ae)

I've tried to do it in InkScape and it looks like it handles the letter-spacing differently (see image 3)

[image]

The style in the inkscape for the text is

```
font-size:17.6389px;line-height:1.25;text-align:center;text-decoration-color:#000000;letter-spacing:5.29167px;writing-mode:vertical-lr;text-anchor:middle;white-space:pre;fill:#990000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:3.77953;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:stroke fill markers;stop-color:#000000
```

and for textPath is

```
font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:17.6389px;font-family:Arial;-inkscape-font-specification:Arial
```

I've tried to use some of these attributes, but I cannot get the same result in D3. I would like the letters to be straight as in InkScape

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It might be impossible to center the letter with the `letter-spacing` attribute to be tilted symetrically.

I ended up creating a function that add non-breakable spaces between every character `d.data.split("").join("\xa0".repeat(d.space))` where `d.data` is the text and `d.space` is the number of spaces inbetween every letter. This is just good for me now and give the following result.

[image]